# Javascript slideshow issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow

Having a problem where my images are covered by whitespace using a javascript slideshow plugin and i believe the issue lies in the javascript, checked all the html and css and nothing there seems to be causing the issue. Basically the top and bottom portions of the image are literally obscured, very annoying.

Website: www.nokwin.com

Thanks in advance,
Nick.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your html/css, nothing appeared incorrect, so I checked your image source:

http://www.nokwin.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/slide2-940x198.jpg

Your image was cropped when you uploaded it, apparently.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the #slider height. It's already at 298px. you probably need to go down to 198 or whatever the height of the images is.

Comment: Hi Roland, thanks for the reply. I've tried that to no avail, however i think i've found the issue. When i add an image to Wordpress featured, it kinda crops the image as you see on the homepage (the plugin uses this method). Nevermind, thanks for the reply!